# Maven: POM modules and submodules hierarchy

Tags: maven, structure, pom.xml

My project is structured like this:

```
.
 |--module
 |  `-- pom.xml
 |  --submodule
 |    `-- pom.xml
 `-- pom.xml
```

The POM's (simplified):

- Project:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <name>Project</name>
    <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module</module>     
    </modules>
    (...)
</project>
```

- Module:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module</artifactId>
    <name>Module</name>
    <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>submodule</module>      
    </modules>
    (...)
</project>
```

- Submodule:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
        <artifactId>module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>submodule</artifactId>
    <name>Submodule</name>
    <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    (...)
</project>
```

When run `maven install` in POM's *project* or *module* the project is built sucessfully. But, when run in *submodule* occours this error:

**Failed to execute goal on project submodule: Could not find artifact org.myorg:project:pom:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT**

Why my submodule not find the POM *project*? The relative path is specified.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing which i noticed is that every sub-module which has a parent contains the line:

```
<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

which is useless, cause it's default in maven or in other word just remove it.

Furthermore in a multimodule build you shouldn't define the version. In case if the groupId is always the same you can omit the groupId as well, cause the current module inherits the version from it's parent.

module: pom.xml

```
<project>
    <parent>...
    </parent>    
    <artifactId>module</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Module</name>

    <modules>
        <module>submodule</module>      
    </modules>
    (...)
</project>
```

Apart from that you can't go into a sub-module and call

```
mvn install
```

If you like to install a separate module of a multi-module build you should use a thing like this:

```
mvn -amd -pl submodule install
```

which will do what you like to do, but usually you should install a full mulit-module build unless you exactly know what you are doing.
The options *-amd* is an abbrevation for *--also-make-dependents*. The *-pl* is an abbreviation for *--projects* to define a list of project which should be made during the call.

Comment: -amd made my day, we have three levels of depth in our restructure of our maven project and I was having trouble building modules 2 levels down

Comment: Just use it from root level and give `mvn -amd -pl submodule/subsubmodule install`.

Comment: "... you can't go into a sub-module and call `mvn install`".  @khmarbaise, why not?
Using `-pl` will build only the module specified, if I specify a module which itself has its own submodules, the submodules will not be built, unless I explicitly specify them too, so in this case `-pl` option is less convenient than `cd` into the submodule and `mvn install`ing it.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to run `mvn install` on root project it will creates the artifact in your local maven repo. From the second time on wards you can run sub module only. If you don't run on root project maven wont create any artifact for your project so when you run on sub module it unable to find the artifact from the maven repo.